# Android: Click Listener Actions

Tags: android

I don't know to explain this but here i go, so i have a populated list... so each item i long press a item from that list an image button will appear its a Delete button actually.. so when i long press another item on the list i want to make that button on the first item i clicked to be hidden... its like every time i long click an item a image button appears and when i click another item, that button will be hidden and the button from which i clicked the new item will be shown.. any inputs as to how to do this will be much appreciated, or if u can give me some effecient way in doing this.. please do share. tnx much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

Assuming you're using a Adapter for the list...

```
    final ImageButton prevButton=null;
    row.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {          
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
            ImageButton currButton=row.findViewById(R.id.<button_id>);
            currButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if(prevButton!=null)
                prevButton.setVisibility(View.gone);
            prevButton=currButton;
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: yep used myown adapte for my list..  is this button dynamically created cuz mine is on the xml.. :D

Comment: yep its working already.. kinds combine urs and the one below u :D tnx much dude

Answer (score 1):

You could just keep track of the previous delete button, since only one is allowed. In the long click listener you can delete the previous button and create a new one.

```
ImageButton prevDelete = null;

...

list.setOnItemLongClickListener (new OnItemLongClickListener() {
  public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id)      {
        deleteButton(prevButton); // check if not null in the function
        prevDelete = createButton(view); // draw button at view
        return true;
  }
});
```

You have probably already implemented the functions `createButton` and `deleteButton`.

Comment: is this dynamically defined, the button?.. cuz mine is xml defined

Comment: Then it may be best to hide or just move the button. You can access the button through `ImageButton myButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.my_button);`

Comment: yep yep its ok already.. i've used ur suggestion and the one above u :D tnx dude

Answer (score 0):

The question is pretty confusing... But from what understood i figure out you need to detect a long press on a list item. Have you tried the [AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener.html).

```
somelist.setOnItemLongClickListener (new OnItemLongClickListener() {
  public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    //do your stuff of showing\hiding button here...
  }
});
```

Comment: no dats not what i meant... i fully understood  the longClicklistener but what i do not know is this situation.. that when i long click a certain item a button appears and when i long click another item.. i want to hide the other button and make another button reappear on the sleected item